# Azure Biztalk Services to On-Premises IBM ESB Communication

Tags: azure, biztalk, paas

I am working on a Hybrid solution in which a Azure BizTalk services (**PaaS model**) need to connect On-Premises IBM ESB. I have tried the "HybridConnection" to connect with on-premises service but with no result.

- How a BizTalk service can connect to On-Premises web service (non WCF).
- Is there any LOB adapter available for IBM ESB which can be added in BizTalk Adapter services?

Thanks

Comment: No, there are no LOB adapters for Azure BizTalk Services for IBM products yet.  Can you expose the IBM ESB as a REST API and connect to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternative approach.
You can create a worker role in Azure, which can connect to the on-prem IBM ESB. Once the worker role gets the messages from the ESB, the worker role can put those messages on the Azure Service Bus. From there, your Azure BizTalk Services bridge can listen to the bus and fetch the messages.

I am already doing that for a project, where my worker role connects to an on-prem MQ server, and it works great.

Also, look into the new API Apps on Azure, they may provide another solution as well.